# how to get string array object values to another class in android

Tags: android

this is my base adapter class
this class itemnames having all the fooditemnames i want to pr

```
enter code here
 public class MainMenulist extends BaseAdapter {
int i;
  String qrimage;
  Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
  Bitmap[] bmps;
  Activity activity = null;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  private ImageView[] mImages;
  String[] itemimage;
  TextView[] tv;
  String itemname;
   public String[] itemnames;
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public MainMenulist(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {

    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

      for ( i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
        qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
        itemname = image.getString("menuname");
        itemnames[i] = itemname;


        byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                                            qrimageBytes.length);
        int width = 100;
        int height = 100;
        resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                                                  true);
        bmps[i] = bmp;

        mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
        mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

        mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);


        // tv[i].setText(itemname);
      }
      System.out.println(itemnames[i]);
      System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }



  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi=convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenulistview, null);


    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.menutext);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);    
    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    text.setText(itemnames[position]);



    return vi;


  }


}
```

this is the   another class ManagerHandset.java,i want to print itemnames[] in the above class.i want to get itemnames in the ManagerHandset.java.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Write a class `MyMain` like-

`class MyMain extends Application(){....}`

Whenver the app starts, this class will be called. Now, you maitain a static instance of your `itemnames[]` in that class like-

```
class MyMain extends Application(){
 public static Object itemNames[];
}
```

Now, instantiate `itemNames` using `MyMain.itemNames = this.itemNames;` wherever you have the value for `itemNames`. Now, your `itemNames` is available to use for you throughout the application. Happy Coding!

Comment: the above code performs a listview . i want click first item means it goes to another page . second item means it goes to another page .. how can i give please tell me

Comment: Then you should have provided `onItemClick()` too man. Anyways, code in my answer works for ANY screen in your app, since its an application scope. So you can use it anywhere in your app. Make sure your class MyMain has a public visibility and your Object[] itemNames has public and static modifiers.